# Can I pass a function (and get its ReturnType) to a generic TypeScript type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, typescript-generics

So my code is as follows. Ideally I'd like to achieve the following as a type:
`LoginPayload<login>`.

I can't figure out the constructs to pass in any function as a generic parameter and get its return type.

```
export type LoginPayload = ReturnType<typeof login>

const login = createAction('customer/login', function prepare({ username, password }: LoginRequest) {
  return { payload: { username, password } }
})
```

What I'd like to achieve:

```
export type LoginPayload<F> = ReturnType<typeof F>

const login = createAction('customer/login', function prepare({ username, password }: LoginRequest) {
  return { payload: { username, password } }
})

//use: LoginPayload<login>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can't use instance as generic parameter, it needs to be type.

Comment: Do you mean the type of `const login` which holds the return type of `createAction` or the return type of `prepare` callback? Does `typeof login` already answer your question how to get that type?

Comment: Hi @ford04 Yes it does. The first code snippet actually gives me what I want, I just want to make it generic so that I can pass any function I want into it and get that return type.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if that is what you are seeking, but I'll give it a try:

Assuming you use `redux-actions` package, the return type of `login`(the function created by invoking [`createAction`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/5344bfc80508c53a23dae37b860fb0c905ff7b24/types/redux-actions/index.d.ts#L86)) will be [`Action<Payload>`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/5344bfc80508c53a23dae37b860fb0c905ff7b24/types/redux-actions/index.d.ts#L18). `Payload` is a type parameter, which is inferred from the return type of the passed in callback `prepare`.

[Action](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/5344bfc80508c53a23dae37b860fb0c905ff7b24/types/redux-actions/index.d.ts#L18) (from redux-actions):

```
export interface BaseAction {
    type: string;
}

export interface Action<Payload> extends BaseAction {
    payload?: Payload;
    error?: boolean;
}
```

If you cannot use an explicit, known type for the `prepare` callback return type, `Payload` can be inferred like this (assumes `string` type for user + pw in the example):

```
type InferPayload<T> = T extends Action<infer I> ? I : never

/*
type Payload = {
    payload: {
        username: string;
        password: string;
    };
}
*/
type Payload = InferPayload<ReturnType<typeof login>>
```

So all in all `Action<Payload>` will have this type:

```
{
    payload?: {
        payload: {
            username: string;
            password: string;
        };
    } | undefined;
    error?: boolean | undefined;
    type: string;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgIUwGdgBBbGBCJOAbwCg4m4YBPMYALjiJimQDmAbnoBfevVCRYiFGiy445StQA8ABUysANhEwATAHxxQqJPqIFiZClRoNmcMFt0GA-N0069+kY7RQ0B5wAEYQENrAmEgi4pLg0PBsHEq21ABiAK5IaUgADKoASsYAvHAAFACUcCXGhSJSiSzseMp2WTkqSACMqgAq3QA0cMU1FTDd3APVtSMNCTLJrbkduQBM-UNwfWvDo2XlE1NbMGtTazN189JJLaldq10AzJvDO29Pe6Xjk9snZ9tdiwnlMnpc5vEbs0Um0MtlcgAWV6Aj5vBFfMaHX4DYanc64kHbT4sBFTBHg+qQppLe7teFdUhIVhFb7lAB0HMwUAERG40VYAG0ALoUkT0fTAbDaLl4dD0uxwbBQKKoWFIDQuHyGcqMZg4Lp9FrcXj8JACQa6pjObwGADCyswMGg3DVjzsBS8riM9EqLpW8uoBTVGptRkMYolUplcDlnQVSpVNi6Ia9w1I3O62stcH1dkNHGNfEEFsc1q99pVztpcLj1F66YEW09Wp9foeAZ6qgbW2DzYMhnDEkj0uVMY7iodqtyKZ8aYzc4Eayzjlz1HzXB4RbNJeYZZ8FcdVddHY23YXQL73t91aQbuop-nSm5QN7mv7g-FkpHsvHCcdSbsGcDAXHtnwXJ5lz1XJ10LU1zWzPc7UnI9-VrJAXjPJ9F3A4ZL0MVsbzvdCu0fBsX25YlX1DAcIy-aNY1yCdEyo1MsNA7CsMo7kEUgphVyQGDNzgncrTffQDydKA2zpNCkUwsicKw9E4Dwgjj1kkjG3PRSG2UlitQ-GkBjGQpgBgTIoAElpVCWCB0CY-81Xw+gaQAGQgARkFMgBHTJgF4MYHGYTISEszAAFsNxNQQEOIIgAHdoH0WCYribBqAC3RPJoMo-ynLpygAcmwEKnUiqAAHosuQQrhgYronGVZxlXKWg4BCtAkAi4BhmcIgEqSuBRG4dzsp8vzeGqILlXMyy6CcMTuDajqwsi3q4sSqB9CGoaxEqCQKoAKhcu5L0C2LQyW7NHBWrrIpSs0-EcXcNqSh7hGzURYnoQ6KpOlIAEkkHQNBL36b4+hMEAzAsG9VGQEGoDgAHjDcZG4G4JBgAANzQCQaTOsogcRsHTNmqyOBslo7LgaqkAHfG7jJiyKeAUbkDGfT+0ZlJmcs9d2aQUyiAiXHtrKABRcBon0UySqgIgEFx7RmT51nBecmkpeccw5YsxXleZPoIahmHLAgEIACtJRgXU0ch0xgHMSwEbQOAAHk4DRtqBQAaVkOAAGtgFYGn3aFbhtZlvWFaV4AVdUd2-aFYxRAxuAsdxqBdSmIQgA)